# Are some natural languages better for expressing mathematical concepts than others?

Tags: reference-request, language-use

I don't know if this is the best stack exchange for this question, but I couldn't think of a better one. Please migrate it to an appropriate stack exchange, if this one is not appropriate. Anyway, my question is, are some human languages better for expressing mathematical concepts than other languages? I am asking because it is my belief that German is better than English for expressing mathematical concepts and doing mathematics. Even if that is not true, I am certain that not all languages are equally suited for every single purpose. Also, has anyone in the academic literature discussed this question? I would like some references.

Comment: What makes you believe that German is any better at expressing mathematics than English?  Why do you believe that some languages are better than others at expressing mathematical ideas?

Comment: There is research on how much better Chinese is for understanding place value. Eleven is something along the lines of ten-and-one. Thirty one would be three-tens-and-one (thought English isn't so bad for this one).

Comment: As a German native speaker who publishes all his research in English, I find the idea that one of the two languages were better suited for expressing mathematical concepts really far-fetched.

Comment: Well, I doubt the native language of Hawaii would be as good as English for that purpose right now, but one can always "upgrade" any language for any purposes by adding new words either by borrowing the roots and using native prefixes and suffixes, or by creating new words based on existing material. If I don't mistake, that was how Hebrew was upgraded from something that was good only for the times of king Solomon to something having words for all modern concepts including advanced math.

Comment: @fedja: Indeed, there's an [institute](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academy_of_the_Hebrew_Language) in Israel that invents new word in Hebrew.

Comment: When you say "German is better than English for expressing mathematical concepts", it suggests to me that German is your own native language.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Not necessarily. It was only 2 centuries ago when the standard science communication language was Latin and one rather famous French mathematician wrote in a letter to his friend after going over some personal stuff in French something like "Now I'd like to talk some math, so I'll switch to Latin; French is no good for such matters".

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps taking things to their extreme there are languages which lack simple numbering like the language of the Brazilian Amazonian people the [Pirahã](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirah%C3%A3_language) which appears to have only words for one and two (or small quantity and large quantity) according to some authorities. This obviously restricts their ability to count and to compare sizes of groups.

Answer (score 3):

This question reminds me of the so-called [Hopi time controversy.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopi_time_controversy) In 1958, Stuart Chase [asserted](https://cs.nyu.edu/%7Edavise/papers/Whorf.pdf) (see page 3) that a person whose native language is Hopi has less trouble grappling with the "fourth dimension" than does somebody whose native language is, for example, English. Although intriguing, the theory is unfounded and not widely accepted by linguists.

I think the same negative conclusions will apply to any speculation that there is a particular language which is best suited for learning mathematics.

A narrower but well supported phenomenon is Spatial-Numerical Association of Response Codes (SNARC effect) of Dehaene *et al.* Admittedly, this has more to do with cognitive parsing of numerical data than high-level mathematics. The idea is that when presented with small numbers, a person will parse them faster if they are presented on the left, while larger numbers should be presented on the right, as we think about a number line. However, there is [research](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7227642/) explaining that this effect is reversed for people whose native language is one where writing proceeds from right to left, i.e., "right-starters."

Comment: Indeed.  The idea that language shapes thought is very much tied up in the works of Whorf and Sapir, and is largely discredited in modern linguistics and neurology.  As an (irrelevant) aside, about 10% of my students are Hopi, and they seem to do no better (nor worse) than any of my other students. :D

Comment: I guess I'll need to brush up on linguistics. My sense, from having lived in a 2nd language at 16, is that our language is shaped (somewhat) by what language we're thinking in.

Answer (score 1):

Let me give you an example in two languages: English (Dutch), and let's talk about tables (tafels [ˈtafəls]) and tables (tabellen [taˈbɛllən]):
A table (tafel) is the piece of furniture at which you can sit and eat and pile stuff on.
In primary school, you learn about multiplication tables (tafels van vermenigvuldiging), and apparently, children have no problems accepting that the word "table (tafel)" is used for this purpose.
Later on, you learn about tables (tabellen) as grids on a piece of paper, containing information, grouped by columns and rows.
In fact, the tables of multiplication (tafels van vermenigvuldiging) are not actual tables (tafels) but more like tables (tabellen), so that's a very fine nuance, getting "lost in translation".

Answer (score 1):

There is mathematics and then there is mathematics.

Languages do presumably affect the speed at which children learn basic number words.

It is known that children learn Danish (in general, not specific to mathematics) slower than Norwegian and Swedish while very young, but then catch up and soon there is no difference. I also just now read a book about mathematical difficulties in the Norwegian context, which specifically names the "-ten -numbers"; tretten (13), fjorten (14), and so on, up to nitten (19). Children might instead write these as for example 31, since the three (tre) is named first.

What follows is guessing on my part based on the two known things above. I guess that most children understand and get past these issues fairly quickly, and afterwards there are no significant differences. In particular, once one gets all the way to research mathematics, there is almost certainly no difference. However, there might always be individual issues that might be caused by the language to a single person, or maybe at a given age a given language has a minor edge.

In addition to number words, we might consider a word like "polygon" in English, which is Greek (also to most English-speakers), and compare it to monikulmio, mangekant, månghörning, and so on, which specify that there are many angles or sides, and do it in a language the speakers understand.

Some languages might also have concepts and ways of stating things others lack: like "puolet enemmän" and "puolet vähemmän" in Finnish and the corresponding expressions in at least one Sami language. But, again, I doubt these make a difference in the long run.

Comment: German native speaker here, we have those -ten numbers as well. I remember that when we were in elementary school, a friend would write the 3 of dreizehn (temporally) before the 1, but (spacially) in the correct place, like 713: 7 -> 7 3 -> 713.